# Issue with PHPmailer and memory limit

Tags: php, apache, phpmailer

I am well aware that this question has been asked multiple times but none of them had a working answer for me. I am getting:

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 262144 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 7168 bytes) in /some/dir/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php on line 1373

and my memory limit is set much higher then that in both /etc/php/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php/cli/php.ini. I have also set php memory limit within the class and in the script that calls it so I am now at a loss. If I run the script over CLI it works fine but over a site it doesn't. Doesn't really make any sense to me...

I am running PHP 5.4.13 on Gentoo and need to get this up and running, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: running `phpinfo()` inside the script that's causing the memory error will show you the currently-in-effect settings ("Local" column in the output) and what .ini files were used to establish those settings. But even with that, nothing says that somewhere else in your script there's a memory_limit() call that's LOWERING the limit.

Answer (score 0):

For the first php has different settings for cli and site. You can write simple script:

```
<?php
#i.php
phpinfo();
```

and look up memory_limit setting. You can change it in php script

Comment: I had memory_limit set in MB with 512M, this was also showing up in phpinfo, changing this to just be bytes seems to have solved the problem... not something that has broken it on other systems but we know that gentoo likes to be different!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your memory limit in php.ini has an M at the end of it.

I had 512 in there, and when I changed it to 512M ....no more problem

z